# Initialize object from Dictionary. Overwriting Values when appending to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to populate class objects based on schema in a csv file. without having to hard code anything.

Based on the code below, when I append an object to the list, it overwrites the previous object of the same type. I attempted to use the Copy module specifically copy.deepcopy() but it did not work.

Can someone explain the cause of this? I think it is related to how I retrieve the class object from the Dictionary and append it to the list.

from copy import deepcopy

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d


class AnotherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, aa, bb, cc, dd):
        self.aa = aa
        self.bb = bb
        self.cc = cc
        self.dd = dd


class LookUpValues(object):
    LOOKUP_DICTIONARY = {
        "SCHEMA_A": SomeClass,
        "SCHEMA_B": AnotherClass
    }


def get_object_list(csv_data):
    obj_list = []
    for item in csv_data:
        some_obj = LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]]

        for column in item[1]:
            setattr(some_obj, column[0], column[1])
        obj_list.append(some_obj)

    return obj_list


def get_object_list_deepcopy(csv_data):
    obj_list = []
    for item in csv_data:
        some_obj = LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]]

        for column in item[1]:
            setattr(some_obj, column[0], column[1])
        obj_list.append(deepcopy(some_obj))

    return obj_list


def print_object_list(object_list):
    for i, obj in enumerate(object_list):
        if i < 1:
            print(obj.a)
        else:
            print(obj.aa)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_from_csv = [
        ["SCHEMA_A", [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]],
        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 2), ('bb', 4), ('cc', 6), ('dd', 8)]],
        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 3), ('bb', 5), ('cc', 7), ('dd', 9)]]
    ]

    result_1 = get_object_list(data_from_csv)
    result_2 = get_object_list_deepcopy(data_from_csv)

    print_object_list(result_1)
    print_object_list(result_2)
```

**Edit 1**
I managed to solve it - but is it really the most Pythonic way to do it?

```
some_obj = LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]].__new__(LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]])
```

**Edit 2**
the schema might not have all the attributes. so unpacking them won't work

```
data_from_csv = [
    ["SCHEMA_A", [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]],
    ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 2), ('bb', 4), ('cc', 6)]],
    ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 3), ('bb', 5), ('cc', 7), ('dd', 9)]]
]
```

Comment: I guess I should of put the output.

iteration one   = 1
iteration two   = 3 # here I am expecting a 2
iteration three = 3

Comment: If the schema doesn't have all the attributes, then how can you initialize your class? You would have to make your class take default arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize an object, use:

```
some_obj = LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]](**dict(item[1]))
```

And as long as we are on the subject of what is Pythonic, stop wrapping your dictionary in a useless class and accessing it through a class-level attribute:

```
LOOKUP_DICTIONARY = {
        "SCHEMA_A": SomeClass,
        "SCHEMA_B": AnotherClass
    }

def get_object_list(csv_data):
    obj_list = []
    for item in csv_data:
        some_obj = LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]](**dict(item[1]))
        obj_list.append(some_obj)

    return obj_list

data_from_csv = [
        ["SCHEMA_A", [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]],
        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 2), ('bb', 4), ('cc', 6), ('dd', 8)]],
        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 3), ('bb', 5), ('cc', 7), ('dd', 9)]]
]

result_1 = get_object_list(data_from_csv)
```

In an ipython session:

```
In [9]: result_1
Out[9]:
[<__main__.SomeClass at 0x103a5b6a0>,
 <__main__.AnotherClass at 0x103a5b710>,
 <__main__.AnotherClass at 0x103a5b748>]

In [11]: ob = result_1[0]

In [12]: ob.a, ob.b, ob.c
Out[12]: (1, 2, 3)

In [13]: ob = result_1[1]

In [14]: ob.aa, ob.bb, ob.cc
Out[14]: (2, 4, 6)

In [15]: ob = result_1[2]

In [16]: ob.aa, ob.bb, ob.cc
Out[16]: (3, 5, 7)
```

Comment: I guess I should of clarified, what you would in this scenario?

'data_from_csv = ['
'        ["SCHEMA_A", [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]],'
'        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 2), ('bb', 4), ('cc', 6)]],'
'        ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 3), ('bb', 5), ('cc', 7), ('dd', 9)]]'
'    ]'

Comment: @dfresh22 sorry, isn't that exactly what you have above? I just forgot to print the `d` and `dd` attributes...

Comment: yes, but all '(**dict(item[1]))' just unpacks the list.

Comment: @dfresh22 No, it calls the class using the call operator, and passes the result of making a dictionary from the list of tuples, and *then* uses keyword-unpacking. It works. I've shown you the output of running the above code... There was an errant `dict(*item)` in my original answer, a leftover from another approach, but the above works as written. You can see the results I've posted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilage your solution did work, but say that not all the variables are in the tuple. ["SCHEMA_B", [('aa', 2), ('bb', 4), ('cc', 6)]],

Comment: @dfresh22 then you can write your class to take defaut arguments to `__init__` or use a default value when you call the class constructor.... the former seems appropriate.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivilage my apologies. you are correct. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating instances of the classes. Rather you are writing the values to the class objects. You need create an instances.

Comment: Thank Dan. that indeed will throw a too few arguments error cause it is attempting to initialize the object without any args. 

Wondering what the most pythonic way to solve this would be. I mean this would solve it, but is this truly the best way to do it?

Comment: `some_obj = LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]].__new__(LookUpValues.LOOKUP_DICTIONARY[item[0]])`

Comment: using `__new__` directly is *certainly not pythonic*